# Algorithm for tracking number of req

Tags: algorithm

I have  an api that is used to register req, each req is sale in a shop with an amount. 
ex.
Sale:{timestamp: 23212312312
Amount: 500£}

Then I have a function statistics which is responsible for giving me details of the sales done in last 60 seconds.
Statistics will return:
avg: average  of the amount of all the sales done in the last 60 s
min: min amount  of the sales done in last 60s
max: max amount
sum: sum of amount of all the sales in last 60 sec
count: number of sales done  in the last 60s

This function should be O(1) in space and time. Now if we ignore space req, should one use a linked list to store the sales occured in last 60 s and continuously update it? or should one update it when statistics function is called. How can this be done in O(1) space?

My solution:
This is my approach to solving this problem:
Each time we sell something add that item to a linkedlist.
Since java linkedlist has a pointer to first and last element first element will point to the first sale that happend 60s from now. when we do a sale we remove the elements from the beginning of the list till we are inside out 60s time frame. when we call statistics we take the current time - 60 s to find the time stamp and use it to remove the elements from the beginning of the list. But when to calculate min,max avg and sum I need to loop through the list => O(n) in both space and time.

Comment: Min max avg is of the amounts of the sales that occured in the last 60 seconds

Comment: If not o (1) how should one solve this? Can we get o (1) for time? If statistics func has to loop through all the sales in last 60s to compute min max avg and sum it would be O(N)

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556155

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your findings.

Comment: done added my approach to the problem

Comment: Perhaps the answer is to accumulate statistics for one second, then keep the result while accumulating the statistics for the next second. The function returns the statistics for the last full second. For example, if the function is called at time 10:00:30.420, then it would return the statistics that were computed for the interval 10:00:29.000 to 10:00:29.999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to divide the interval into 1-second "buckets".<sup>1</sup>  Each bucket can contain a count, sum, min, and max value.  Each time a new sale is reported, update the appropriate bucket for the timestamp.  When a statistics query is made, aggregate the buckets to get the overall count, sum, etc.  Also, for each API call (update or query), discard any buckets older than 60 seconds and create new, empty buckets to replace them.

If we want to include the number of buckets as a parameter `k`, in addition to number of sales `n`, then updating a single bucket is `O(1)` and querying statistics is `O(k)`.  Updating the list of buckets is `O(k)` in a naive implementation, but this can be avoided by only updating each bucket when accessing it.  Space requirements are `O(k)`.

For any fixed number of buckets this reduces to `O(1)` time and space complexity for each operation, regardless of the sales volume.

<sup>1</sup>You can adjust the bucket interval to trade off between precision and computation time.

Comment: So for the first call just create one bucket and add the value to it. This bucket will have a range in milisecond that will correspond to one second. next time it is called again create a new bucket if it more that a second from the last call etc. this bucket. Will we get O(1) for time ? we wont get it for space.

Comment: @user2975699 Yes, there are a constant number of buckets so the time complexity of all operations is `O(1)`.

Comment: @user2975699 Clarified the time and space complexity.  `O(1)` means that the function is bounded by a constant.  60 times a constant is still a constant.